# How could I send a value to MYSQL from a dropdown selection without refresh page and without click the "send" button?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In a PHP page I have a simple selection with some values like this:

```
<div class="container">      
  <section>
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select an activity</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </section>      
</div>
```

I have a database MYSQL to store the choiced `value` like this:

table name=`user_favorite` with 2 columns respectively called `items` and `values`

<kbd>items</kbd><kbd>values</kbd>
<kbd>item1</kbd>      <kbd>value1</kbd>      
<kbd>item2</kbd>      <kbd>value2</kbd>      
etc.

When a user select an item from the dropdown list I wish to send automatically to MYSQL the `value` chosen (inside the `values` column) without click on a send button. 
Is it possible and how to achieve?

Comment: you should use `ajax`

Comment: @NishantSolanki of course but how to? an example is really appreciate

Comment: take a look at this ...http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: @NishantSolanki I need to store values not retrieve from my database

Comment: @NishantSolanki please don't refer to w3schools.com

Comment: @Simone just change the `select query with update query`... it was just a reference to you that how to use ajax...

Comment: @Daan yeh I know it sucks.. but still good for beginners... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NishantSolanki said, you should use Ajax. Here an example using jQuery.

HTML FILE:

```
<div class="container">      
   <section>
       <select id="options">
           <option value="" disabled selected>Select an activity</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
       </select>
   </section>      
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#options").on("change", function(){ //listen when the option change   
            var optionValue = jQuery(this).val();   //get the new value

            $.ajax({
                url: "fileWhichSaveTheValue.php", //php file which recive the new value and save it to the database
                data: { "newValue": optionValue },  //send the new value
                method: "POST"                    //use POST method
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP FILE:

```
$newValue = $_POST["newValue"]; //if you used POST method on the javascript, you have to use $_POST here to get the data


//HERE YOUR MYSQL CONNECTION AND YOUR QUERY FOR SAVING THE VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onchange event on select

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
     $item = $_POST['item'];
     $link = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
     mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
     //write your sql query to enter into table
    }
 ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">      
  <section>
    <select onchange="save_record(this.value);">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select an activity</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </section>      
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function save_record(item){
    //call an ajax here to post item 
    $.post( "your_php_page_name.php",
      {item:item}, 
      function( data ) {
        // do something after ajax result
      });
}
</script>
```

On your php page you can retrieve post data by `$_POST` variable

Comment: very nice, since I'm not familiar with Ajax, could you please show me the insert code?

Comment: if you didn't used ajax before i can post the code for the same

Comment: I didn't used Ajax before, and I need to send to the table `user_favorite` on column `values` the `value` chosen

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me...why do I need `$.post( "your_php_page_name.php"` if I'm on the same page? And how to send data to MYSQL?

Comment: Here you have to mention that on which page you want to send your post request. If you want to send it on same page name your page here and check `if($_POST)` at top.